# What is the meaning of converter operating point statement from the textbook "Fundamentals of Power Electronics" by Erickson?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, isolation

"Isolated converters
with **large variations in operating point** tend to utilize their power devices more poorly than non-isolated
converters which function at a **single operating point**".

[image: Text book snap]

What does the author imply by large variations in operating point?
Both isolated and non isolated topologies would have variations in input voltage and load current.

**Why would non isolated converters have single operating point?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book, the authors introduce the concept of switch utilization \$U\$ which involves the delivered power \$P_{out}\$ and the stress \$S\$ endured by the power switch(es). For a single-switch converter, like a flyback for instance, \$U=\frac{P_{out}}{S}\$ and it is interesting to check what duty ratio maximizes the switch utilization and use this value to calculate the rest of the elements. Based on the book examples, I have re-derived the formulas and it is shown below for a CCM flyback converter with idealized waveforms:

[image]

The calculations show that the switch utilization peaks for a duty ratio of 33% for the CCM flyback. Because the transformer turns ratio \$N\$ does not play a role in the definition of \$U\$, the switch utilization remains the same with or without isolation for a buck-boost and its isolated version (a flyback) or a SEPIC and its isolated version.

If you now run the same calculations for the buck converter, the switch utilization reaches 1 when \$D\$ approaches 100% and it makes sense as it implies that \$V_{out}\$ is close to \$V_{in}\$ and the switch is almost always closed along the switching period. Same for a boost converter when the output voltage is not far from the input voltage and the switch is closed only a very small amount of time: the voltage stress is the smallest on the switch.

The authors now run calculations for an isolated single-single switch converter like a forward and the switch utilization peaks to 0.353 versus 1 with the buck. This is because a single-switch forward converter needs a reset winding which is usually chosen with the same turns ratio as the primary. It naturally limits the duty ratio below 0.5 and incurs a voltage stress of twice the input voltage. However, again, it depends on the difference between the input and output voltages. Assume you want to deliver 5 V from a source varying between 10 V to 50 V. Below are the values computed for the buck and the forward at 10 and 50 V, selecting a turns ratio for the forward so that the duty ratio remains below 50% at the lowest input:

[image]

You see that the isolated version is always worse than the non-isolated one in this example. Now optimize the forward converter for a single operating point like 50 V, the buck converter sees a large differential voltage while you can optimize the turns ratio of the forward converter which now leads the race for the switch utilization.

Answer (score 3):

Operating point would mean variations in input voltage which would require variations in duty cycle.

I agree the sentence is ambiguous because there are four possible combinations but it is talking as if only two exist. I think it should say something like "isolated converters are less efficient than non-isolated converters" and "converters with large variations in their operating point will use their components less optimally than converters that operate only at a single operating point"

Comment: 4 possible combinations?

Comment: Synchronous/Asynchronous + Single/Varying Operating points. Four combinations.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of semiconductor devices depends on their voltage and current capability. Higher voltage capability devices are slower to switch and have more parasitic capacitance than lower voltage rated devices. Similarly high current switches (e.g. MOSFETs) also have larger parasitics.

If a DCDC converter which is *capable* of operating a high current or voltage, but is only operating using a lower input voltage or load current, then it will have unnecessarily large (excessive voltage rating) switches, or excessively large switches. This degrades system conversion efficiency as all this excess 'baggage' needs to be driven and controlled. This is what is meant by saying they use their power devices more poorly.

In other words, while it is good practice to have some safety margin in selecting switching devices, excessive capability is not ideal.